# Java generic constructors syntax and purpose

Tags: java, generics

Java constructors can be generic: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

However I can't find a good example of how to declare and invoke generic constructor. Moreover I don't understand the purpose of generic constructor as type parameter's scope is limited to constructor.

Having class with generic constructor:

```
public class MyClass {

    public <T> MyClass(T data) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

we invoke it as:

```
MyClass obj = new <Integer>MyClass(12);
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of generic constructor? Can you show an example from JDK or your own example?
2. Why statement like

   ```
   Integer val = new <String>Integer(100);
   ```

is compiled without error even when class Integer doesn't have generic constructor?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I think it compiles because the type is misplaced. The correct way would be `new Integer<String>(100);` or `new MyClass<Integer>(12);`.

Comment: @Tom `new MyClass<Integer>` would be used if *the class itself* had a parameter, like `class MyClass<T>`. But in this case, it's the constructor that has the parameter, and writing it this way is the standard way of calling generic methods or constructors.

Answer (score 6):

One purpose of a generic constructor can be the same as for some generic methods: To make sure that several arguments refer to the same type.

Consider the following example (yes, it's a bit contrived, but should show the point) :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class GenericConstructorTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Collection<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        ClassWithParam c0 = new <String>ClassWithParam("String", strings);
    }
}

class ClassWithParam
{
    public <T> ClassWithParam(T data, Collection<T> collection) 
    {
        collection.add(data);
    }
}
```

It does not matter for the class or its constructor *which* type exactly is used there. It's only important to know that the collection that was given as the second argument can take elements of the type that was given as the first argument.

(I'd like to show a more realistic, practical example, but think that it's rather rarely necessary to parameterize a constructor this way, and one could even consider that this is just a "side effect" of the possibility to parameterize *methods*, and the fact that there is no reason to explicitly *disallow* this for constructors...)

---

EDIT As per request in the comment, and example where the given arguments are atually *used*. It's still rather contrived. More realistic examples could be structurally similar and refer to some sorts of *listeners*, but would involve much more code:

```
public class GenericConstructorTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Callback<String> callback = new Callback<String>();
        ClassWithParam c0 = new <String>ClassWithParam("String", callback);
        c0.execute();
    }
}

class ClassWithParam
{
    private Runnable runnable;

    public <T> ClassWithParam(final T data, final Callback<T> callback) 
    {
        runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                callback.call(data);
            }
        };
    }

    void execute()
    {
        runnable.run();
    }
}

class Callback<T>
{
    void call(T t)
    {
        System.out.println("Called with "+t);
    }
}
```

---

The second example that you posted

```
Integer val = new <String>Integer(100);
```

does not compile in Eclipse with Java 7. It complains

> The constructor Integer(int) of type Integer is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

In Java 8, this is allowed, although it still issues a warning:

> Unused type arguments for the non generic constructor Integer(int) of type Integer; it should not be parameterized with arguments

(If this difference is what you're actually interested in, you might consider asking this as a separate question)

Comment: FWIW, it *does* compile with the Sun Java 7 compiler.  I don't know whether it's the Sun compiler or the Eclipse compiler that's at fault, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Interesting, I should have tested this. It does not even print a warning. Maybe I'll dig though the JLS to see whether this can be considered as a bug in the Eclipse compiler (from a short websearch, there seem to be *related* bugs, but have not yet found one that exactly matches *this* case)

Comment: It's hard to imagine practical use of such constructor: it modifies input collection but can't then store it into field of class or just return it.

Comment: @ako As emphasized in the answer: The example was only for illustration purposes. Every more realistic use case that I could think of would be overly complicated and involve some code that would "hide" the actual point: There are several arguments, and they are somehow related via their type - and this relation is expressed via the type argument.

Comment: @ako I tried to think of another example that can actually be run and actually *does* something, but it's still rather abstract. I'm not aware of any *really* practical use-case in terms of classes in the standard library that use generic constructors...

Comment: @Marco13 thank you, your second example is much better